# Copy from vector<T> to vector<U>, using C++11 features

Tags: boost, c++11, vector, copy, emplace

I have a `std::vector<char*>` that I want to copy into a `std::vector<MemRef>`, in a performance-critical section.  I've looked at solutions using `std::copy()`, `boost::make_transform_iterator`, `std::vector<int> newVec; newVec.reserve(oldVec.size()); .. push_back()` and I have no idea what's best.

MemRef is a small object containing a `char*` and a `size_t` length.

I'm using GCC 4.4.7 with `--std=g++0x` so I get *some* c++ features, including `emplace_back()` which is nice for avoiding constructors and copying.

I think I'm better off not constructing the vector afresh each time, but rather using the vector `clear()` method to empty it, which as I understand allows it to refill to capacity without reallocation.

I'd appreciate help getting my head around this!

Comment: If you don't have a _specific_ code problem, and just want to know what's best -- _profile it_.  It's the only way to know.

Comment: @Chad, Sorry - are you saying this isn't specific enough for the forum?

Comment: FYI, by and large (though not exclusively) `C++11` features add higher-level constructs and functions, not more performant ones.

Comment: @Chad, I'm not sure he necessarily *knows* all the ways it can be done.

Comment: Use the constructor that takes iterators

Comment: @PaulDraper: I was thinking of emplace_back, and the "move semantics", which seem like performance boosters.

Comment: What are you holding in your `std::vector<char*>`?  Strings?  How do you know the length (`strlen`?)

Comment: @Chad, yes, the char*s are null-terminated 'C'-style strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think std::copy would have pretty good performance, especially with the one note I see on [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)

> In practice, implementations of std::copy avoid multiple assignments
>   and use bulk copy functions such as std::memmove if the value type is
>   TriviallyCopyable

If the types require conversion then I would do this:

```
class MemRef
{
  public:
    MemRef(char * astr) : ptr_( astr), size_( strlen( astr)) { }
...
} ;

vecMem.insert(vecMem.end(), cstrVec.begin(), cstrVec.end()) ;
```

This allows vecMem to figure out how much space it needs to reserve in one go.

Comment: Please correct URL (algorithm/copy).  SO won't allow "trivial edits.

Comment: This is as good a place to start as any, although I can't imagine bulk copy coming into play when each element must be converted.

Comment: I didn't know if you already had an automatic conversion between the types.  I have my own type similar to your `MemRef` that has a constructor that takes a `const char *`